# Problem in setting path for android sdk in ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu-9.10

```
 export PATH=${/home/mohit/}:<android-sdk-linux_86>/tools
```

this is what i am using..

error:--

```
bash: PATH=${/home/mohit/}:: bad substitution
```

this is the path of sdk

```
mohit@mohit-laptop:~/android-sdk-linux_86$ pwd
/home/mohit/android-sdk-linux_86
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically you will use

```
export PATH=${PATH}:<added path here>
```

try that, to append to your $PATH variable, or just remove the ${} and set it directly, if you wish to replace it. Also keep in mind, this change is not permanent unless you add this to your .bashrc or .bash_profile or equivalent scripts. You can reload them with the

```
source .bash_profile
```

command without having to re-login.

Comment: @Alex can u tell me exact path.. I m not able to figure this out.

Comment: export PATH=${PATH}:"~/mohit/android-sdk-linux_86/tools"

Comment: or you can use: export PATH=${PATH}:"${HOME}/mohit/android-sdk-linux_86/tools"
make sure $HOME environment var is defined in your shell

Comment: @Alex, "$HOME" is the full path to the user's home directory... likewise "~" is the user's home directory... "/home/mohit/" is the home folder for the user name "mohit".

Comment: @Alex, also, I think you meant "source ~/.bash_profile" and not "script ~/.bash_profile".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `${/home/mohit/}` is actually treating `/home/mohit/` as a variable and attempting to dereference it. My guess is that what you really wanted to do was:

```
export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/android-sdk-linux_86/tools"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your /etc/profile to add the path you need.
Like this:

```
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.6.0_30
CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib
export JAVA_HOME
export CLASSPATH
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin
```

It is global.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a script file under /etc/profile.d/ and we can use it as global