# Error in setting up TITANIUM in Ubuntu?

Tags: android, ubuntu, titanium, ubuntu-11.04, titanium-mobile

i have been following the steps from http://developer.appcelerator.com/get_started and getting an error

```
       Could not locate the Android SDK at the given path
```

Tried this http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/122998/could-not-locate-the-android-sdk-at-the-given-path , [Problem in setting path for android sdk in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616588/problem-in-setting-path-for-android-sdk-in-ubuntu) and several other blogs and discussions but not able to set up. Any possible reason what step I am  missing or where it needs to be done some work. Thanks in Advance !!!

**----EDIT----**

Check this Also, http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/128204/error-while-installing-titanium-in-ubuntu-

After checking further more it seems like SDK for Titanium is missing rather than the Android SDK, and its unable to download it.

```
  Updating Titanium SDK's has encountered a problem.
  Error extracting zip file
  No such file or directory
```

Comment: Could you post which steps you made to get the SDK running?

Comment: @franzi Check Now !! Edited the Question !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reinstalled the OS and did a fresh install for titanium and everything went smooth. I think I had deleted the .titanium folder(hidden) from my home directory earlier which deleted the default SDK with titanium download. So, as it was unable to find any existing SDK that is why it throwing an error in updating SDk.